# Changing timezone redis server (time)

Tags: time, redis, timezone

The time command on the redis-cli returns the current server time. How can I change the timezone on the redis server?

Note that redis gives me UTC+0300 timezone, whereas date on the Linux server shows me UTC+0700, which is my correct timezone.

Restarting the Linux server doesn't help.

Restarting the Linux server and restart redis-server doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Redis [`TIME`](https://redis.io/commands/time/) command returns two values:

1. A [Unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), in terms of seconds
2. A number of microseconds already passed within the value given by the first number

For example:

```
redis> TIME
1) "1674676800"
2) "123456"
```

That result represents 2023-01-25 20:00:00.123456 UTC.

Unix timestamps are *always* in terms of UTC, because they are defined as the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

Thus, time zone is not reflected by the output of the `TIME` command at all.  The number you see is not UTC+3, nor should it be UTC+7, it is just UTC.

If you are *actually* seeing a value that is three hours ahead of UTC, then your system's *clock* is set incorrectly - not your system's time zone.  You should sync your clock with an NTP server to correct it.

You can check the UTC time on your Linux server from a bash prompt with `date -u`.  You can also call `date +%s` to get a Unix timestamp, which should approximately match the first number returned by Redis.